# Add attachment metadata after wp_insert_attachment()

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a plugin that saves email attachments to a custom disk folder and then adds them as attachments to a custom post type. This all works correctly so far, but I need to save a couple of metadata values. The metadata will always be the same (so far) and it needs to be on any attachment filetype (.zip, .jpg, .txt, etc)

Can anyone tell me how to add a metadata key/value in this code:

```
$filename = $attachment['filename'];
$mimetype = $attachment['mimetype'];
$data     = $attachment['data'];

$upload = wp_upload_bits( $filename, null, $data );

if ( ! $upload['error'] ) {

    $attachment_data = array(
        'guid'           => trailingslashit( $upload['url']) . basename( $filename ),
        'post_mime_type' => $mimetype,
        'post_parent'    => $post_id,
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    );


    $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment_data, $upload['file'], $post_id );

    if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {

        return false;

    } else {

        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $upload['file'] );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attach_data );

        return true;

    }
}
```

$attach_data above always returns empty.